# Design Considerations Behind Creating controller_interface::ControllerInterfaceBase

Tags: ros-control

What were the design considerations behind creating `controller_interface::ControllerInterfaceBase` in ROS2 Control? While it appears there are many `controller_interface::ControllerInterface` [derived classes](https://github.com/search?q=%22public%20controller_interface%3A%3AControllerInterface%22&type=code), I couldn't find any as far as my [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=%22public%20controller_interface%3A%3AControllerInterfaceBase%22&type=code) shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rationale is mentioned [here](https://github.com/light-tech/ros2_control/blob/795b6edc2b84bca3e20325a8bc2cec1d7cf6872d/controller_interface/include/controller_interface/controller_interface_base.hpp#L62-L64): both `ControllerInterface` and `ChainableControllerInterface` inherit from `ControllerInterfaceBase`, but controllers should not.

```
/**
 * Base interface class  for an controller. The interface may not be used to implement a controller.
 * The class provides definitions for `ControllerInterface` and `ChainableControllerInterface`
 * that should be implemented and extended for a specific controller.
 */
```

Comment: Indeed! I've missed ChainableControllerInterface.  Thanks.